# How to remove or hide duplicate value from dropdownlist in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a dropdownlist. where i load my all due client list from database. but one client have one more due amount. so it's loads on my dropdownlist and make duplicate client name's,now i want to remove duplicate clients name.

Here is my dropdownlist.

```
 <label class="form-label">Client Name</label>
                            <select class="form-control"  name="client_id" id="client_id">   
                             <option value="">-Select Client-</option>
                             @foreach($clients as $client)
                             <option value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->client_name}}</option>
                             @endforeach
                            </select>
```

Here, is my tried jquery part.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var map={};
$('#client_id').each(function(){
  if(map[this.value])
  {
    $(this).remove();
  }
  map[this.value]=true;
});
```

});

Comment: I think a server side remove will be more efficient in this case, remove it from `$clients`.

Answer (score 2):

You're very close.

Just change:

```
$('#client_id').each(function(){
```

to:

```
$('#client_id option').each(function(){
```

That will iterate through all the options instead of the single `#client_id`.

**Snippet:**

```js
var map = {};
$('#client_id option').each(function() {
  if (map[this.value]) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
  map[this.value] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="client_id">   
  <option value="">-Select Client-</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'd need to see the rendered HTML to troubleshoot.

Comment: here,is my query.   $clients=DB::table('directdues')
            ->join('clients','directdues.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->select('directdues.*','clients.client_name','clients.addr')
            ->where('directdues.due_amt','>',0.000)
            ->get()

Comment: That shows your code, but it doesn't show the HTML that's the result of the code.  I'd need to see the full HTML to troubleshoot.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/majeed19/90gedjpe/ please,see this here i load the full html and js function.

Comment: That still doesn't show the rendered HTML.  I'm sorry I can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

Using .siblings() (to target sibling option elements), and Attribute Equals Selector [attr='']

```
$(".select option").val(function(idx, val) {
  $(this).siblings("[value='"+ val +"']").remove();
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="com">.com 1</option>
  <option value="net">.net 1</option>
  <option value="com">.com 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="net">.net 2</option> <!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
</select>
```

How it works:

while options are accessed one by one (by .val()) - lookup for .sibling() options that have the same "[value='"+ this.value +"']" and .remove() them.

Comment: This is a nice alternative solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing duplicate values using PHP is neater than using JavaScript in my opinion.

**Solution 1**

Eliminating the duplicates as you selecting from database via Eloquent.

```
// using Model
$clients = Client::get()->groupBy('client_name')->all();

// using DB::class
$clients = DB::table('clients')->get()->groupBy('client_name')->all();
```

**Solution 2**

Using Eloquent `collect()` to eliminate duplicate `client_name`

```
// $clients should be an array
@foreach( collect( $clients )->groupBy('client_name')->all() as $client )
    <option value="{{ $client->id }}">{{ $client->client_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

**Solution 3**

Using jQuery method, just in case you still want to remove the duplicates using jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var map={};
    $('#client_id option').each(function(){
      var val=$(this).val();

      if( map[val] )
      {
          $(this).remove();
          return; // continue to next loop
      }

      // Registering val to map list
      map[val]=1;
 });
```